# Why the array arrangment affects speedup?

Tags: performance, fortran, openmp, gfortran

I'm using gfortran and openmp to write a code for parrallel computing. When testing the code on a desktop machine (equiped with an Intel(R) Core(TM) i3-3220 CPU @ 3.30GHz), I noticed that the way you arrange your data affects significantly the runing time and speedup. Indeed, arranging the array on 1D with nx cells or on 2D with same number of cells that spreads on nxx lines and N_threads rows. Note that N_threads represents the number of used threads.

To better understand and quatify this I write a short code with running exactly the same number of operations. The code is written below:

```
program testMem
Use omp_lib            
implicit real*8 (a-h,o-z)
integer nx,nxx,N_threads 
parameter (N_threads=4,nx=1E8,nxx=int(nx/N_threads))
real*8  x(1:nx)
real*8  xx(1:nxx,0:N_threads-1)

x(1:nx)=0.
xx(1:nxx,0:N_threads-1)=0.

call system_clock(count_rate=icr)
timerRate=real(icr)     

CALL OMP_SET_NUM_THREADS(N_threads)

! 1D
call system_clock(ic1)
t0=omp_get_wtime()      
!$omp parallel do shared (x) private(i,j)
do i=1,nx
  do j=1,100 
    x(i)=x(i)+real(j*j)
  end do
end do 
!$omp end parallel do
call system_clock(ic2)      
t1=omp_get_wtime()
write (*,*) (ic2-ic1)/timerRate,t1-t0

! 2D
call system_clock(ic1)
t0=omp_get_wtime()   
!$omp parallel do shared(x) private(i_threads,i,j)
do i_threads=0,N_threads-1
  do i=1,nxx
    do j=1,100 
      xx(i,i_threads)=xx(i,i_threads)+real(j*j)
    end do
  end do 
end do
!$omp end parallel do
call system_clock(ic2)      
t1=omp_get_wtime()
write (*,*) (ic2-ic1)/timerRate,t1-t0

end program
```

My expectations was that the parallel version of the code run faster than the serial one independently of the arrangement of the array. However, I find that my machine spend

```
                   1D           2D
serial            5.96         5.96     
1thread          21.30         5.98
2threads         10.72         2.98
3threads          8.20         8.11
4threads          6.30         2.91
```

I wonder if someone could explain what is happening here? Why in the 1D section the time increase from ~6s to ~20s from a serial (without compiling with -fopenmp) to parallel with 1 thread? why the behavior of 2D array is so different from the one observed for 1D array?

As suggested by @IanBush I use implicit none and declare all variable with real simple precision. Running the code now takes

```
                   1D           2D
serial            4.61         4.13     
1thread          12.16         4.18
2threads          6.14         2.09
3threads          5.46         5.65
4threads          4.63         1.85
```

The running time is better since real simple precision is 32 bits long while real*8 (double precision) is 64 bits long. However, the problem remains the same.

I also clarify as suggested by @IanBush that I use GNU Fortran (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3 installed on Ubuntu 12.04. The code is compiled with gfortran -mcmodel=medium -O3 -fopenmp -o cmd.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Could you tell us what compiler, what version of the compiler, and what compiler and link flags you are using. And please use Implicit None - it is my opinion that it's not really worth answering questions that don't bother to do the very basics in defensive coding. And please don't use the totally non-standard, non-portable real*8.

Comment: If your question is about how openmp affects dead code elimination, that certainly depends on the compiler and options. If it's not worth your time to examine generated code it may not be worth ours.

Comment: Thank you @IanBush for your suggestions and interest. 

The compiler that I use in my desktop machine is a gfortran installed on an Ubuntu 12.04. The version of the compiler is GNU Fortran (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.3-1ubuntu5) 4.6.3. The code is compiled with gfortran -mcmodel=medium -O3 -fopenmp -o. To my knowledge the real*8 is a double precision and is a standard kind of real. The use of implicit declaration is not supposed to affect the calculation duration. However, I run the code with implicit none and default real. The behavior is the same. I edit my question to give all these informations.

Comment: You are not measuring what you think you are. The first parallel region is where the OpenMP runtime creates the thread pool, so you are including that, significant, time in your first measurement, which will account for much of the difference. Add a separate, empty, untimed, parallel region before doing any timing...

Comment: Thank you @JimCownie for your suggestion. Creating the thread pool should takes a time that doesn't exceed a few ms. Thus it might affect slightly the behavior of the code, but not in the discussed magnitude order. Furthermore, I do a test with permuting the 1D and 2D sections and the runtime is the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The behavior described above is due to a false sharing problem that affects negatively the 1D part. The problem is well known in literature and appears, in brief, when multi-threads operate on the same cache memory line. In the 1D part, this might happen frequently, since 2 threads might acess to adjacent array elements. In contrast, the 2D part of the above code, each thread work on it own column. Thus, since fortran is column-order, the different threads work on data that never feet in the same cache line.

To avoid the false sharing problem, it is suggested to use "padding", i.e. force the threads to access to different cache lines, which means that threads access to array elements that cannot be in the same cache line. Assuming that a cache line can contain 8 real*8, I modified the 1D part to get rid of the false sharing problem as follow

```
! 1D
call system_clock(ic1)
t0=omp_get_wtime()      
!$omp parallel do shared (x) private(i,j,i_leap,ii)
do i=1,int(nx/nCacheSize)
  do i_leap=1,nCacheSize
    ii=(i-1)*nCacheSize+i_leap
    do j=1,100 
      x(ii)=x(ii)+real(j*j)
    end do
  end do
end do 
!$omp end parallel do
call system_clock(ic2)      
t1=omp_get_wtime()
write (*,*) (ic2-ic1)/timerRate,t1-t0
```

Note that nCacheSize is declared as `parameter (nCacheSize=8)`

I test the code on Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-3320M CPU @ 2.60GHz and the results are as follow

```
                   1D           2D
serial            3.99         3.92     
1thread           3.86         3.93
2threads          2.05         2.07
3threads          2.19         5.46
4threads          1.98         1.98
```

The increase of runtime with 3 threads is probably due to the cpu hardware that consists of 2 cores and 2 threads per core.

I underline that `nCacheSize` must be declared as a constant through `parameter (nCacheSize=8)`, otherwize calculating `i_leap` with bounds containing a variable doesn't solve the false sharing problem.